# Print filename if string found

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have four files says - `file1.txt`, `test2.txt`, `file23.txt`, and `tact24.txt` and word/string to search in these files.
If word found in one of file print filename.

Example:

word - `cat`

search `cat` in files - `file1.txt` `test2.txt` `file23.txt` `tact24.txt`

Suppose cat found in `test2.txt` then print only `test2`

Can this be done in one line via `awk`/`sed` commands?

I am trying below- but unable to get what i am expecting

```
grep cat file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt
file1.txt:cat
grep: test2.txt: No such file or directory
grep: file23.txt: No such file or directory
grep: tact24.txt: No such file or directory

grep cat file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt|grep -v "grep"
file1.txt:cat
grep: test2.txt: No such file or directory
grep: file23.txt: No such file or directory
grep: tact24.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

Comment: You quite obviously _don't_ have those four files, only `file1.txt`.  Also, in the title you say you want to print the _filename_, but in the question you say you want to print `test2` if the string is found in `test2.txt`.  What should be printed if the string is found in `test2.doc`?

Answer (score 2):

To print the filename (without its filename suffix, if it has one) of the file that contains a given string:

```
awk '!found[FILENAME]++ && /string/ { fname = FILENAME; sub("\\.[^/]*$", "", fname); print fname }' file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt
```

This would detect the string `string` (used here as a regular expression, so special characters would have to be escaped) on any line in the current file, and if a match has not yet been found in that file, the filename without its filename suffix would be printed.  The filename suffix is anything after the *first* dot in the filename.  The way I have written the `sub()` command, it would retain the directory path of the file if this was given on the command line.

If you just want to output the pathname of the file, then use

```
grep -lF 'string' file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt
```

The `-l` option would make `grep` only output the pathnames of the files that contains matches, while `-F` would cause it to treat the `string` as a string and not as a regular expression.

If you give `grep` or `awk` filenames that don't exist, it will complain with errors.  You may want to see these errors (as they indicate that something's wrong), or you may not.  If you don't want to see them, then redirect them to `/dev/null`:

```
grep -lF 'string' file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt 2>/dev/null
```

The `2>` means "redirect the standard error stream to the following location".

Instead of redirecting the error stream to `/dev/null` you could opt for using `grep` with the `-s` option:

```
grep -lsF 'string' file1.txt test2.txt file23.txt tact24.txt
```

Comment: Or, use the `-s` option with `grep` to silence it for nonexistent or unreadable files.

Comment: perhaps `grep -sFl 'string' file*.txt | sed 's/\.txt$//'` to strip off the extension.

Comment: @glennjackman Filenames with newlines and `sed` being a line-oriented editor, and so on...